# Laravel 5.2: withErrors on redirect not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm currently struggling with a Laravel problem I can't fix myself. If I pass errors using withErrors() the errors are not passed to the Error Bag ($errors).

**My Controller (FormController):**

```
public function contact(Request $request) {

        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'message' => 'required',
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput($request->all());
        }

        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

The thing is, also withInput() is not working. Where could the problem come from? I appreciate your help!

**(Part of) the defined routes.php:**

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function(){
    Route::post('/contact', 'FormController@contact');
});
```

**Session config**

```
return [
    'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'memcached'),
    'lifetime' => 120,
    'expire_on_close' => false,
    'encrypt' => false,
    'files' => storage_path('framework/sessions'),
    'connection' => null,
    'table' => 'sessions',
    'lottery' => [2, 100],
    'cookie' => 'session',
    'path' => '/',
    'domain' => null,
    'secure' => false,

];
```

Comment: Does session works for you at all?

Comment: try redirect a route or url instead of back

Comment: @matiit Sessions are working on the rest of the site. When I check the POST to contact() with debugbar "errors" is present in sessions with the right errors.

Comment: @ImtiazPabel I tried this but unfortunately without any changes to this problem..

Comment: Try `... ->withErrors($validator->errors())-> ...`

Comment: Is your route using the web middleware? That might be your problem if nothing regarding sessions is working.

Comment: @btl yes it is using the 'web' middleware group.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin tried it but without any luck.

Comment: Can you post your session config?

Comment: @btl i've added it to the post, memcache is working..!

Comment: Did you found your answer. If yes please share.

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel 5.2 you need to use the `web` middleware in your routes to pass the errors to the view.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    Route::get('/', function() {
        return view('welcome');
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, unfortunately I already use the 'web' middleware group... I heard of problems when exchanging sessions between middleware groups, but I only use the 'web' middleware group.

Answer (score 0):

Don't pass anything to the withInput

```
 if ($validator->fails()) {
      return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
 }
```

and use the old function to get the flashed data

```
$name = $request->old('name');
```

or

```
{{old('name')}}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I tried it but without any luck... I thought it was a Session problem, but the sessions are working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

If the controller that you are redirecting to is also using `withErrors()` function, the error messages in `redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator)` will be overwritten.

But, the old messages are still in session. So you can still read and display them with `session('errors')`:

```
@if ($errors->any())
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul class="my-0">
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@elseif (null !== session('errors') && session('errors')->any())
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul class="my-0">
            @foreach (session('errors')->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be due to session problem. To diagnose this problem use print_r($request->session()). if you are getting different id in session object that means session is not setting up properly.

To get it done open Kernel.php

1. dont specify below line in $middleware array
2. specify these below line in web middleware group and $middlewarePriority array

   \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
   \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,